# Syntax error for time travel of delta sql

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I ran the example in delta doc:

```sql
SELECT * FROM delta.`/delta/events` VERSION AS OF 1
```

But got the following error:

```
mismatched input ‘AS’ expecting {<EOF>, ‘;’}(line 3, pos 44)
```

Does anyone know what is the correct syntax ?

Spark version: 3.1.2

Delta version: 1.0.0

Configure spark as follows:

```
spark.sql.extensions io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
```

Comment: What Spark and delta versions? Extensions are registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not supported in the open source version right now as it requires changes in Spark to support that syntax (the [required changes are committed already](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/34497)).  Specifically, this is a bug in the documentation that was copied from the Databricks Delta documentation. The issue with documentation will be fixed in the next major release - it was [already reported](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/128#issuecomment-924206859).